# is variable I(a*b*c) same as a:b:c in R?

Tags: r

Is variable `I(a*b*c)` same as `a:b:c` in R, showing interaction effect?
If not, what does each mean?

Comment: why don't you experiment? make up a data frame with numeric variables `a`, `b`, `c`, and examine the results of `model.matrix(~I(a*b*c),data =dd)` vs. `model.matrix(~a:b:c, data=dd)`

Answer (score 1):

See `?I`. In a formula it protects `a*b*c` from being interpreted/changed by the formula interface, and passes it along to the interface that handles algebraic expressions. So interpret `a*b*c` essentially as you would outside the formula interface.